# mysql_query doesn't work but db_query does on a simple SELECT query

Tags: 6

I'm receiving the following warning when I use `mysql_query()` in my modules.

> mysql_query(): A link to the server could not be established on line 6

If I use `db_query()`, it works fine.

The code is a simple query with no special characters or variables: `mysql_query("SELECT * FROM custom_nodify WHERE nid = 345");`.

I should mention that this happens with any call to `mysql_query()`.

Do you know why this doesn't work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just to start with let me very clearly say, never **ever** use `mysql_query` unless you really have to (multiple databases with different backends fx).

Why? `db_query` has a lot of security features built in to help prevent SQL injections, and it makes your site database agnostic (you won't have to change code if you change the database backend) and it allows you to use table prefixes without hardcoding them in the queries.

Anyways the reason why mysql_query doesn't work is because you need to create a connection to the database first using the database credentials, something drupal does automatically for you, when you use db_query.

If you really want to throw away all the good Drupal does for you and use mysql_query anyways, take a look at [`mysql_connect`](http://dk.php.net/mysql_connect).

Comment: Wish I could give this +10, just for the 'never **ever** use `mysql_query`' statement. This isn't specific to Drupal; in fact on the main SO site if you answer a question suggesting the use of `mysql_query` you should be prepared for downvotes galore!

Comment: @Clive `mysql_query()` is being used because I HAVE to use MySQL date constructs, and they get misinterpreted by `db_query()`.

Comment: @kylex Ah yeah that's a pain. Might I suggest using the [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) family of functions instead (if it's available on your server; it should be)? It has [many advantages](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1171344/advantages-of-mysqli-over-mysql) over the old functions, not least the ability to use prepared statements

Comment: @kylex, you should really try to use MySQLi or PDO instead of the old mysql library.